# django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters, templatetags

im tried to install django-jalali-date module on Django5.0 . But I encountered the following error:

> django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'jalali_date.templatetags.jalali_tags': No module named 'distutils'

i am tried install this module for convert Gregorian calendar to solar calendar.
I installed it with pip install django-jalali-date and put it in the installed apps

Comment: What python version are you using?